# case statement in where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure with the following code.

```
 alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Product_GetProductByCategoryID] 


@CategoryID uniqueidentifier,
@IsCategory bit=0  
AS  
  BEGIN  

   SELECT     ProductId, ProductCode, ProductName, MRP, MaxDiscount, 
              ShortDescription, ThumbNailImagePath,ThumbNailImagePath1, 
              FullImagePath, IsActive, NoOfBuyer,   
              LongDescription, BrandID, SubCategoryID, CreatedDate,
              LargeThumbnailImagePath, VideoPath  

   FROM         TBM_Product  

   WHERE (case @IsCategory 
           when 0 then  TBM_Product.SubCategoryID
           when 1 then  TBM_Product.CategoryID 
       end) 
            = @CategoryID 

   *AND (case 
       when @IsCategory= 0 then TBM_Product.SubCategoryID = TBM_Product.SubCategoryID
       when @IsCategory= 1 then TBM_Product.SubCategoryID is null 
      end)* 

END
```

what I want is

if(@IsCategory= 1) then

```
   TBM_Product.SubCategoryID is null
```

else

```
 void this and condition
```

how to achieve this.I am getting "incorrect syntax near =" error while compiling the above stored procedure.

Comment: From your code it seems like you are trying to set the @CategoryID variable in the WHERE clause???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use a case statement in your where clause. Instead use the AND/OR operators.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Product_GetProductByCategoryID] 
    @CategoryID uniqueidentifier ,
    @IsCategory bit = 0  
AS  
BEGIN  

SELECT  [ProductId], 
        [ProductCode], 
        [ProductName], 
        [MRP], 
        [MaxDiscount],    
        [ShortDescription],   
        [ThumbNailImagePath],
        [ThumbNailImagePath1], 
        [FullImagePath], 
        [IsActive], 
        [NoOfBuyer],   
        [LongDescription], 
        [BrandID], 
        [SubCategoryID], 
        [CreatedDate],  
        [LargeThumbnailImagePath], 
        [VideoPath],
        @CategoryID = CASE @IsCategory 
                        WHEN 0 THEN  TBM_Product.SubCategoryID
                        WHEN 1 THEN  TBM_Product.CategoryID 
                      END   
FROM    [dbo].[TBM_Product]
WHERE   (@IsCategory = 0 AND TBM_Product.SubCategoryID = TBM_Product.SubCategoryID)
        OR (@IsCategory= 1 AND TBM_Product.SubCategoryID IS NULL)
END
```

Comment: This part: "AND TBM_Product.SubCategoryID = TBM_Product.SubCategoryID" isn't really necessary since they are the same field, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: AND TBM_Product.SubCategoryID = TBM_Product.SubCategoryID is added to void the where clause i.e where (1=1)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT...CASE doesn't work in WHERE conditions, and they don't work like you've written it. You'll have to modify your query and write the condition like this -

```
...
WHERE
    (@IsCategory= 0 AND TBM_Product.SubCategoryID = TBM_Product.SubCategoryID)
    OR
    (@IsCategory= 1 AND TBM_Product.SubCategoryID IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
and ((@Iscategory=1 and TBM_Product.SubCategoryID is null)
    or
    (@Iscategory = 0))
```